# Logical AND operator

Tags: c, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I am little confused with logical AND operator.
I have these 2 lines of code. Here `num` and `j` are both int. I have a situation where both the conditions are satisfied, but I don't know why it's not printing the value of `j`. Can anybody point out the mistakes? Thanks in advance.

```
if(k==1 && num%j==0)
    printf("%d",j);
```

Comment: Well, could you perhaps tell us that situation? :)

Comment: A single line of code does not help solving the issue. You should describe the problem in a better way.

Comment: To debug this problem, print the values of `k`, `j`, `num`, and possibly even `num%j` BEFORE the condition statement to see what they REALLY are. Then do the evaluation by hand with pencil and paper if you're still stuck.

Comment: What are the values of your variables where you think the result should be true and is not?

Comment: sorry everyone;
It was my extreme foolishness.
I got the mistake.

Comment: @user417552: Since this has been resolved, either accept an answer or delete the question. :)

Comment: @user417552:  Also, our curiosity is piqued, and we would like to know what the mistake was - values not what you expected, or output being swallowed somehow.

Comment: My code was absolutely correct.
I was taking the wrong inputs to check it. I apologize to everybody for my carelessness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In plain English, the expression `k == 1 && num % j == 0` is true if and only if `k` equals 1 ***and*** the remainder from dividing `num` by `j` is 0.  Not much more I can say.

Answer (score 1):

There's two possibilities here.  Either you never get to the `printf`, or the output never gets to you.

For the first case, are you sure that `k == 1` and `num % j == 0`?  Giving us the actual numeric values values in your test might help.  Note that if `k` is a floating-point number that's the result of a computation it might be very slightly off from 1.0, and the condition would return false.

For the second case, how are you testing this?  That should print out the value of `j`, but it doesn't flush the output, so if the program terminates abnormally or the console goes away at the end of the program or something you may not see it.  Try `printf("%d\n", j);` or even `fflush(stdout);` to make sure the output is visible on your console or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If conditions are true, there is no problem in your code.

Check the output [here](http://codepad.org/9lQzj7Bw).

Answer (score 0):

you might also want to add an else statement. I cant count how many times this has happened to me. it is a good practice at least when in the initial stages of you coding. do this:

this will help you catch the problem

```
if(k==1 && num%j==0)
    printf("%d",j);
else {
   printf("%d \n",k);
   printf("%d \n",num);
   printf("%d \n",j);
   printf("%d \n",(num%j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine, take a look at this [testcase:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case)

http://ideone.com/1gz8R

So the problem is not with those two lines. Try printing the three values involved right before you get into those lines, you may be surprised by what you see (or don't see).

Answer (score 0):

You should also get in the habit of using parentheses liberally, imo:

```
if(k == 1 && (num % j == 0))
```

at the least.

Comment: Blech!  To me superfluous parentheses detract from readability and suggest that the author was unsure how the language he's using works.

Comment: While this is subjective, I think that parentheses such as this can only add to readability when there might be ambiguity in order of operations.

Comment: Yes, of course it's subjective, but the fact that the above operators could be considered at all ambiguous speaks to me of gross unfamiliarity. It's understandable to forget the precedence rules for less-used (or, at least, less often mixed) operators like `<<`, `&`, `^`, `?:`, and friends, but there's little excuse for not memorizing simple ones like your example. They're pretty intuitive. The boolean operators (`&&`, `||`) have lower precedence (`&&` is the higher of the two) than comparisons (`==`, `<`, etc.), which are lower than arithmetic operators, which follow normal mathematic rules.

Comment: But as far as *aiding* readability, quick, what happens here?  `if(((a + (2 * b)) < (foo() - bar())) || (((foo() < bar()) && (a < b)))) ifTrue(); else ifFalse();`  Parenthesis soup!  Yuck.  The eye simple cannot follow this.  Compare to `if(a + 2 * b < foo() - bar() || foo() < bar() && a < b) ifTrue(); else ifFalse();`.  Knowing the simple precedence rules I outlined earlier, this is easy to follow (although, perhaps not so much in this comment box).